# Football Clock counter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, counter, clock

I need the code for a Football Scoreboard clock counter (that decreases) that I can use for games.  I also need the code for having a button that both stops and starts the clock.  I need to have the clock embedded in a picture file I am creating.  in other words, have it run just like one you would see in a game.

Comment: Lots of needs here.  We need to see you having a go yourself first.

Comment: Would recommend you at least attempt this and post the code as a starting point. Even if it doesn't work, we would have something to work off of. This is just a list of needs...

Comment: No thanks, I'd rather not do your work for you today, or any day.

Answer (score 0):

For the countdown timer. Take a look at this.
http://jchavannes.com/jquery-timer you can tweak the code according to your needs. Hope this helps.